# ListView lag only when loading image for the FIRST time with Picasso

Tags: android, listview, picasso

I am using a ViewHolder setup with my ListView, so I am sure that it is not a recycling issue.

The ListView only lags when the images are loaded in for the fist time, if I scroll back up, everything is smooth.

My simplified getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...

    mPicasso.load(cData.get("url")).into(holder.imagePreviewView);

...
}
```

My XML for the ImageView:

```
 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/image_preview_height"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     android:background="?attr/postPreviewBground" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did u put layout_height of listview as wrap_content. this can cause an initial delay

Comment: I have them set to match_parent.

Comment: the delay is cause u load images on main thread rather than non ui thread, load images from a thread and initally only have place holder for images

Comment: Putting it on another Thread helps, but it stills stutters way too much.

Comment: I HAVE THE SAME PROBLEM!!! Thanks for open this question! .... In my case the images are already in the disk. Here how i call picasso: /*        code         */                   

Picasso.with(mContext).load(new File(cursor.getString(columnIndex)))
.fit().centerInside()    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_while_loading)   .error(R.drawable.image_loading_erro).into(imagem);

Comment: Are you using animation on your listview? I have found a lag on the initial loading only when doing this

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely the system doing a GC_FOR_ALLOC to allocate the memory for the Bitmap you're loading. It's smooth scrolling back up since the bitmap is already loaded and cached in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error easily. You have to throw a thread inside getView(), and inside of that thread, you write the code that you have.

Try this, it works!

Comment: I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should happen from the main thread. at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.checkMain(Utils.java:136)`